# writing to buffer channel more than its capacity

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

overwriting the buffer channel more than its capacity does have any effects ?

Since there is another go routine and main go routine doesn't join with it so no deadlock here

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
        ch := make(chan int, 2)
        go func (){
        ch <- 1
        ch <- 2
        ch <- 4//blocks here but scheduler picked up another go routine
        ch <- 6
        ch <- 10
        //close(ch)
        }()
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
        //for v:=range ch{
        //fmt.Println(<-ch)//1 2 4 6 10
        //}

        
    }
```

Comment: You can't send more values to a buffered channel than its capacity, further sends are blocked until values are received from the channel, making room for the new values. This situation is completely normal, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: @icza Thank you for clarification but what if there is no room to received the further send  values will result in blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because of that no deadlock here

A `go build -race .` would indeed detect no race condition.

But the main reason there is no deadlock, is that the main function exits after the second `fmt.Println(<-ch)`.

Even if the anonymous goroutine is blocked on `ch <- 4`, the all program stops anyway.

Comment: yes thank you for pointing out if there is wait group to joined the two go routines then create deadlock condition letting the main go routine to wait until done from another go routine, Here is the code https://play.golang.org/p/L1xJJp_uHPN